# concurrent.futures block ignored on aws ec2 instance

Tags: python, multithreading, amazon-ec2, concurrent.futures

I am creating a docker image of my python flask application project and deploying it on AWS. One of my programs uses concurrent.futures in order to incorporate some multiprocessing features. But I have realized that AWS is ignoring the whole concurrent.futures block and it results in an error.

pdf_to_img_to_text.py. This program is being called by some other program. It works fine on my local machine. But on my AWS instance, it completely ignores the `with with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:` block and since it does not get anything in the dict_map, it results in `KeyError`. Please guide why the with concurrent.futures block is being ignored on AWS.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
import os
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import image_to_string
import PIL.Image
from PIL import Image
from wand.image import Image as Img
import os
import glob
import concurrent.futures
import time

def no_of_pages(file):
pdf = PdfFileReader(open(file,'rb'))
pages = pdf.getNumPages()
return pages

def ocr(file):
    print("Converting PDF to Image to Text....")
    print(file)
    text = ' '
    im = PIL.Image.open(os.path.join(file))
    text = text + image_to_string(im)
    try:
        os.remove(file)
    except:pass
    return text


os.environ['OMP_THREAD_LIMIT'] = '1' 
def convert_pdf_to_image_to_txt():
    dict_map = {}
    path = "something"
    file = "something"
    f = "something"
    with Img(filename=file, resolution=300) as img:
        img.compression_quality = 99
        img.save(filename = os.path.join('C://Users//aswathi.nambiar//Desktop//Output_Images',f + '.jpg'))

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        image_list = glob.glob(path+"\\*.jpg")
        i = 0
        for img_path,text in zip(image_list,executor.map(ocr,image_list)):
            print(img_path.split("\\")[-1],',',', processed')
            dict_map[img_path.split("\\")[-1]] = text

    print(dict_map)
    pages = no_of_pages(file)
    text = ' '

    for i in range(0,pages):
        print(f+'-'+str(i)+'.jpg')
        print(dict_map[f+'-'+str(i)+'.jpg'])
        text = text + dict_map[f+'-'+str(i)+'.jpg']
    return text
```

Comment: The code is right. What is happening is probably that `glob.glob` is returning an empty list, hence the following `for` loops does not print anything nor it adds anything in `dict_map`. did you try to add `print(image_list)` right after the definition of that variable?

Comment: I have tried to print(path) which is submitted to the glob.glob. But that is not logged in the logger. So i am assuming that the with block is not getting executed. But anywy, it is worth giving a shot to try to print the image_list. @GiacomoAlzetta

Comment: It was a very silly error. The problem was with the separators used. The separator in the code "\\" worked on windows. But on AWS ec2 linux box, it wouldn't work. So used os.path.sep. and now it works!

Comment: I'm happy that you solved your problem. I'd like to suggest you to use `os.path.join` instead of using the separator directly: `os.path.join(path, '*.jpg')`. Also: you should write an answer to your question and accept it (yes it is fine to write answers to your own questions). Finally: be aware that users can see the edit history, so editing the question only removes the content from reading it directly but it is still available.Be careful not to put sensitive data in your posts.